# Applying real life measurements to a digital sculpture

Tags: sculpting, measurement

While sculpting a human body I found myself needing to make sure that the main body points are set apart a certain amount of cm to match the measurements of an existing person. Is there a tool like calipers in Zbrush or a way to measure a part of a body, change the units accordingly to real life example and then be able to measure other parts relatively to the first measurement made?
For example I know that the distance between clavicles and pubic bone of a model is 57 cm. I need to make sure that everything else in the body of my sculpt will be relative to my model's measurements. How can I achieve it?
Huge thanks to anyone reaching out to help!

Comment: Sounds like [MeasureIt](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/addons/3d_view/measureit.html) can help with what you want to do. It ships with Blender and can show the distance between to vertices of your choice.

Comment: It worked out for me with Measureit, thanks! Though I had to resize the whole sculpture to fit the measurements I think it's even better now cause it matches real life size now